# Difference between split and preg_split in php

Tags: php

Can anybody tell me the main difference between split and preg_split in php?
As both functions works on regular expressions.

Thanks

Comment: Reading the manual actually would have answered your question. http://php.net is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

[`split`](http://php.net/split) uses [POSIX ERE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#ere) and [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) uses [PCRE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html). See this [PHP manual page on the differences of PCRE from POSIX ERE](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.posix) as well as the [flavor comparison on Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html).

Answer (score 0):

Easy, split() :

> Warning
>
> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this
>   feature is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

preg_split() uses PERL-compatible regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_split()`, which uses a Perl-compatible regular expression syntax, which is faster.alternative to `split()`.

Answer (score 0):

split() uses POSIX as it's regex extension while preg_split() uses PCRE(Perl Compatible Regular Expression) as it's regex extension. PCRE has extended regex features.

Another main difference is that split is case insensitive while preg_split uses case sensitive regex. For case sensitive regex we used to use [spliti](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spliti.php).

(Everything above from http://phppot.com/php/reasons-why-split-is-deprecated/)

So, the main difference between PCRE and POSIX regex as per php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

> As of PHP 5.3.0, the POSIX Regex extension is deprecated. There are a
>   number of differences between POSIX regex and PCRE regex. This page
>   lists the most notable ones that are necessary to know when converting
>   to PCRE.
>
> - The PCRE functions require that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters.
> - **Unlike POSIX, the PCRE extension does not have dedicated functions for case-insensitive matching**. Instead, this is supported using the i
>     (PCRE_CASELESS) pattern modifier. Other pattern modifiers are also
>     available for changing the matching strategy.
> - **The POSIX functions find the longest of the leftmost match, but PCRE stops on the first valid match.** If the string doesn't match at all it
>     makes no difference, but if it matches it may have dramatic effects on
>     both the resulting match and the matching speed. To illustrate this
>     difference, consider the following example from "Mastering Regular
>     Expressions" by Jeffrey Friedl. Using the pattern
>     one(self)?(selfsufficient)? on the string oneselfsufficient with PCRE
>     will result in matching oneself, but using POSIX the result will be
>     the full string oneselfsufficient. Both (sub)strings match the
>     original string, but POSIX requires that the longest be the result.
> - The POSIX definition of a "character class" differs from that of PCRE. Simple bracket expressions to match a set of explicit characters
>     are supported in the form of PCRE character classes but POSIX
>     collating elements, character classes and character equivalents are
>     not supported. Supplying an expression with a character class that
>     both starts and ends with :, . or = characters to PCRE is interpreted
>     as an attempt to use one of these unsupported features and causes a
>     compilation error.